# Draw circle behind particular characters of UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I am trying to draw circle behind particular parts of UILabel characters without having to use several labels or recompute frames.

I know that I can insert an image into UILabel using attributed text but I want the circle to stand behind the numbers (from 1 to 9). I don't want to store images from 1 to 9.
I also cannot find any pod achieving this.

```
    let fullText = NSMutableAttributedString()

    let imageAttachment = NSTextAttachment()
    imageAttachment.image = UIImage(named: "\(number)_\(color == .yellow ? "yellow" : "gray")")
    let imageString = NSAttributedString(attachment: imageAttachment)
    let endString = NSAttributedString("nouveaux")

    fullString.append(imageString)
    fullString.append(endString)

    mainLabel.attributedText = fullString
```

[image]

**EDIT**

I want to draw circle behind each digit of a string.
I would like it to be a generic tool if possible, some kind of parser that returns an attributed string if possible, a unique UIView if not.
Another use case is **"4 messages | chat 2"** (4 being yellow, 2 being gray)

Comment: Please show what you've already tried, what didn't work, code samples etc. Please read [ask] and [mcve] and then [edit] your question showing the _minimum_ code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: If you're saying that 1 and nouveaux are in the same label, then why not separate them into 2 different UILabels and make a custom one to round the label into a yellow circle using cornerRadius?

Comment: Why not a custom `UIView` which draws the circle and number with core animation layers and a separate label. This is more efficient, I guess.

Comment: @Mochi Because I would like it to be generic there can be 0 up to 2 "insertion points" for a given model. I would like to handle circle insertion behind a character without having to deal with 4 labels and changing their constraints at runtime. I want it to be generic and insert circle behind each digit of a given string.

Comment: So the number is always the first or last character in the label?

Comment: Yes, that can simplify things, possible inputs for my use case "xxxxx", "(1-9)xxxxx", "(1-9)xxxxx(1-9)", "xxxxx(1-9)". Numbers of characters can vary. Single line label.

Comment: "I know that I can insert an image into UILabel using attributed text but I want the circle to stand behind the numbers (from 1 to 9). I don't want to store images from 1 to 9." I don't understand the difficulty. Why not draw the digit-with-circle-behind-it in real time and insert it using attributed text, exactly as you say? There is no need to "store" anything, you're completely in charge of color, and you have just one label.

Comment: To allow to choose the circle color and to avoid storing 9*number_of_colors images in assets, I would prefer draw the circle in swift code instead of using images.

Comment: And that is exactly what my previous comment suggested you should do. What's the difficulty?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't understand why you don't just use a utility function that draws the digit-in-a-circle in real time. That way, you can have any digit font, circle size, digit color, and circle color that you like. For example:

```
func circleAroundDigit(_ num:Int, circleColor:UIColor,
                       digitColor:UIColor, diameter:CGFloat,
                       font:UIFont) -> UIImage {
    precondition((0...9).contains(num), "digit is not a digit")
    let p = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    p.alignment = .center
    let s = NSAttributedString(string: String(num), attributes:
        [.font:font, .foregroundColor:digitColor, .paragraphStyle:p])
    let r = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: CGSize(width:diameter, height:diameter))
    return r.image {con in
        circleColor.setFill()
        con.cgContext.fillEllipse(in:
            CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: diameter, height: diameter))
        s.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: diameter / 2 - font.lineHeight / 2,
                          width: diameter, height: diameter))
    }
}
```

Here's how to use it:

```
let im = circleAroundDigit(3, circleColor: .yellow, 
    digitColor: .white, diameter: 30, font:UIFont(name: "GillSans", size: 20)!)
```

Here's the resulting image; note, though, that every aspect of this can be tweaked just by calling the function differently:

[image]

Okay, so now you've got an image. You say you already know how to insert an image inline into an attributed string and display that as part of the label, so I won't explain how to do that:

[image]

Comment: can we make it useable for multiple digits?

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty straightforward using a `UIStackView`, setting the corner radius of the coloured view's layer…

[image]

result…

[image]

or with 2 stack views in an outer stack view≥

[image]

result…

[image]